# pandas - not in index

Tags: pandas, indexing, nan

I'm trying to replace the nan values in column 'A' (for which the first one appears in row 9) with the previous value is the row before

```
y = len(df)
for i in range(1,y):
     if (np.isnan(df.ix[i,'A'])):
         df.ix[i,'A'] = dfH.ix[i-1,'A']
```

gives the error

```
KeyError: "[9 'A'] not in index"
```

but row 9 column A is clearly in my dataFrame. What is going on here?

Comment: there is a function fillna to handle this of Dataframe. such as 'backfill'

Comment: but how can you fill it with the prevoius row entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `fillna` with `ffill` method:

```
df['A'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
df['A'].ffill(inplace = True)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,np.nan,3]})
print (df)
     A
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  3.0

df['A'].ffill(inplace = True)

print (df)
     A
0  1.0
1  1.0
2  3.0
```